# Recursion to separate one word into three or more words java

Tags: java, recursion, io

I am trying to write a program that will take input from dictionary.txt document and will store the words in a dictionary list, and then determine if the word can be broken up into three or more words and if yes, then printing out the original word followed by the new words for example `disconsolateness:disc on so lateness` would be the output in the document composedMore.txt. Right now, the code just continues to run, but I am not getting any output and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. I have posted my code below, and the input is any word in the dictionary.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CompositionTwo
{
    private static List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String []args) { 
        File inputFile = new File("dictionary.txt");
        File outputFile = new File("composedMore.txt");
        Scanner in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;

        try {
            in = new Scanner(inputFile);
            out = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String input = in.next();
                dictionary.add(input);
                String output = splitWord(input, "");
                if (output != "") {
                    out.println(input + ":" + output);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An IOException has occurred during output process.");
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }

    } 

    public static String splitWord(String word, String output) {

        if (word.length() == 0) {
            output = output;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 1; i <= word.length(); i++) {
                // consider all prefixes of current String
                String prefix = word.substring(0, i);

                // if the prefix is present in the dictionary, add prefix to the
                // output String and recurse for remaining String

                if (dictionary.contains(prefix)) {
                    splitWord(word.substring(i), output + " " + prefix);
                }
            }
        }

        return output;
    }  
}
```

Comment: To start you will probably want to finish populating the dictionary before you try and split the word.  The first time you call splitWord there is only one word in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

First Add all the words into dictionary and then check each word afterwards because you need to compare with all words in the file
The process you were adopting just compared the words before the word being compared

```
import java.util.*;

 import java.io.*;

 public class CompositionTwo
 {

private static List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String []args) { 
    File inputFile = new File("dictionary.txt");
    File outputFile = new File("composedMore.txt");
    Scanner in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    String word;

    try {
        in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        out = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
        //Read the file indictionary
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String input = in.next();
            dictionary.add(input);
        }

        //Check All the words in dictionary for Splitting
        for(int i=0;i<dictionary.size();i++)
        {
            String output = splitWord(dictionary.get(i), "");
            if (!"".equals(output)) {
                String outa[] = output.split("\\s") ;
                if(outa.length >= 3) // Check if 3 words are created as output
                {
                System.out.println(dictionary.get(i) + ":" + output);
                out.println(dictionary.get(i) + ":" + output);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

} 

public static String splitWord(String word, String output) {

    if (word.length() == 0) {
        return output;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= word.length(); i++) {
            // consider all prefixes of current String
            String prefix = word.substring(0, i);

            // if the prefix is present in the dictionary, add prefix to the
            // output String and recurse for remaining String

            if (dictionary.contains(prefix)) {
                return splitWord(word.substring(i), output + " " + prefix);
            }
        }
    }

    return output ;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this dictionary:

```
disc
on
so
lateness
```

And suppose you run your program against the string `disconsolateness`. 
I made some changes to load the dictionary first and then call the recursive method `splitWord`.

You should know that recursive methods are called putting altogether in a stack, and then go returning one call by one. So I chose to change the recursive call to:

```java
return prefix + " " + splitWord(word.substring(i), output);
```

so that each word found would be concatenated after each method call.

Obviously, as you already did, my stop condition remains when there are no more characters in variable `output`.

```java
    package io.gdfb.questions;

    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class CompositionTwo {
        private static List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            loadDictionary();

            File outputFile = new File("composedMore.txt");
            PrintWriter out = null;
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
                String output = splitWord(args[0], "");
                if (output != "") {
                    out.println(args[0] + ":" + output);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An IOException has occurred during output process.");
            } finally {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }

        }

        private static void loadDictionary() {
            InputStream inputFile = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dictionary.txt");
            Scanner in = null;
            try {
                in = new Scanner(inputFile);
                while (in.hasNext()) {
                    String input = in.next();
                    dictionary.add(input);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
        }

        public static String splitWord(String word, String output) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= word.length(); i++) {
                // consider all prefixes of current String
                String prefix = word.substring(0, i);
                // if the prefix is present in the dictionary, add prefix to the
                // output String and recurse for remaining String
                if (dictionary.contains(prefix)) {
                    return prefix + " " + splitWord(word.substring(i), output);
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
```